# MSE Minimized by Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, means, mean-square-error

In the Gaussian case, it is well-known that the MSE, is minimizer by the mean value.  However, in general, if $X \in L^2(\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})$, is a random-variable in $\mathbb{R}$, then is the does
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X] = \inf_{Z \in L^2(\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})} \;\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[(X-Z)^2\right]?
$$

The argmin, is the conditional expectation, but what about the min itself?

Comment: ..... variance?

Comment: Probably not, since that isn't true for a 1-dimensional Gaussian.